# Is there a tool that helps manipulate with colors

Tags: html, css, less

In less we can do arithmetic operations with colors.
for example:

`startColor * middleColor = endColor`

`startColor - middleColor = endColor`

Is there a tool that helps find middleColor if we know startColor and endColor?

thanks for the answers, but i do not want to do operations with colors by hand. Please give me just link to a tool. It must be somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

You can pass it any color, and perform color-related operations, such as adding/removing hue, saturation, lightness, alpha, etc. And you can have it return colors in various forms, such as rgb(a), hsl(a), and hex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strsplit` or `split` functions, get the values for each color (rgb, red green blue) do the maths.

You can convert them to decimal for better understanding as default in web is hexdecimal.